# Python - NaN return (pandas - resample function)

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I'm doing a finance study based on the youtube link below and I would like to understand why I got the NaN return instead of the expected calculation. What do I need to do in this script to reach the expected value?

YouTube case: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UpbpvP0m5d8

```
import investpy as env
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

lt = ['ABEV3','CEAB3','ENBR3','FLRY3','IRBR3','ITSA4','JHSF3','STBP3']
prices = pd.DataFrame()
for i in lt:
    df = env.get_stock_historical_data(stock=i, from_date='01/01/2020', to_date='29/05/2020',  country='brazil')
    df['Ativo'] = i
    prices = pd.concat([prices, df], sort=True)

pivoted = prices.pivot(columns='Ativo', values='Close')

e_r = pivoted.resample('Y').last().pct_change().mean()
e_r
```

Return:

```
Ativo
ABEV3   NaN
CEAB3   NaN
ENBR3   NaN
FLRY3   NaN
IRBR3   NaN
ITSA4   NaN
JHSF3   NaN
STBP3   NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: do all your stocks have yearly data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the 'from_date' to have more than one year of data.

You current script returns one row and .pct_change() on one row of data returns NaN, because there is no previous row to compare against.

When I changed from_date to '01/01/2018'

```
import investpy as env
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

lt = ['ABEV3','CEAB3','ENBR3','FLRY3','IRBR3','ITSA4','JHSF3','STBP3']
prices = pd.DataFrame()
for i in lt:
    df = env.get_stock_historical_data(stock=i, from_date='01/01/2018', to_date='29/05/2020',  country='brazil')
    df['Ativo'] = i
    prices = pd.concat([prices, df], sort=True)

pivoted = prices.pivot(columns='Ativo', values='Close')

e_r = pivoted.resample('Y').last().pct_change().mean()
e_r
```

I get the following output:

```
Ativo
ABEV3   -0.043025
CEAB3   -0.464669
ENBR3    0.180655
FLRY3    0.191976
IRBR3   -0.175084
ITSA4   -0.035767
JHSF3    1.283291
STBP3    0.223627
dtype: float64
```